# File path not found when code is deployed on a remote server

Tags: node.js, express, filepath, enoent

I have the following directory structure for my node/express app:

```
/ 
    /client_side_code
        - object00.png
    /server_side_code
        - server.js
```

When running a local server on port 3000, my server.js script accesses object00.png successfully with the following code:

```
var pathToImage = __dirname + "/../client_side_code/original_object_images";

fs.readdirSync(pathToImage).forEach(function(file,e) {
    console.log(file);
});
```

Now, when I upload my application to a remote server (Heroku), the console says that this path can't be found. Specifically, I get the following error message in the console:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/server_side_code/../client_side_code/original_object_images
```

As you can see, the object00.png image can no longer be found. I thought using **__dirname** would also work on a remote server since it begins a relative path. Any thoughts as how I can allow this image to be accessed when it's hosted on a remote server?

Comment: Can you show me the folder structure for your server?

Comment: The directory structure I gave above is the structure on my server. Are you thinking that the directory structure changed when I pushed the code to the server?

Comment: Is this folder empty while deploying on Heroku?

Comment: Oh wait i just cloned the app onto my local machine and saw that the directory is missing. I'm going to look into that and let you know but in the mean time thank you for your that suggestion.

Comment: Yes, That's the problem.